# Sendgrid returns SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and I follow the book Learn-ruby-on-rails by Daniel Kehoe. I have set up my sengrid login details correctly on the Ubuntu enviroment. echo $ SENDGRID_USERNAME returns my username correctly.

However, I still get "SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name" error when I submit the contact form. I have tried to hardcode the login details and I still get the same errors. my configuration settings i smtp.sendgrid.net on port 587 and I allow send mails in development.

Please what am I not doing right.
Thanks a lot.

My user_mailer.rb is as shown:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
#default :from => "do-not-reply@example.com"

def contact_email(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail( to: => Rails.application.secrets.owner_email, from: => @contact.email, subject: => "Website Visit")
end
```

end

while the contacts_controller.rb is shown below:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

def new 
    @contact = Contact.new

end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(secure_params)
    if @contact.valid?
       UserMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver_now
        #TODO send message
        flash[:notice] = "Message sent from #{@contact.name}."
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new
    end 
end

private 

def secure_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :content)
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose from an omission in the config/enviroments/development.rb file
I replaced

```
 user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider
```

with:

```
 user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username
```

and the problem was solved